# How to add three numbers using javascript with div id as result?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me? This is just a basic thing but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to add 3+5+5 using javascript but it doesn't seem to work. And the sum should also show up when I click the button add.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Adding three numbers</title>
     <script>
        function add(3,5,5) {
        var a = +'3';
        var b = +'5';
        var c = +'5';
        var x = +a + +b + +c;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "x";
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div> 
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add(3,5,5)">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are more issues than lines of code. I would suggest you to start studying JavaScript from fundamentals paying attention to all the programming concepts too

Comment: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML` all good until ` = "x"`, that's a string which equals "x" not your x variable

Comment: needless to say that you don't need to `+'5'` !!? just `var c = 5;`

Comment: This is not the way for immediate function invocation. Plus you can't manipulate DOM elements until they are rendedred.

Comment: var a = 3; var b = 5; var c =5; var x = a + b + c;

Comment: @pookie we do help people, that's why we are here as you, but when you see that the issue involves really big problems with fundamentals of programming, the best help you can give to someone is the suggestion to study better

Comment: No, you can do better than tell them to "go study better". You can give them an example, point out a couple of mistakes, like to a good resource, or offer a solution.

Comment: @pookie I say do both.  Tell them to study more, as these skills are fundamentals to JS, and then try to assist.

Comment: @everyone - thanks for the insights guys! it's just that I guess i've been lurking too much around here that I picked up the incorrect inputs or maybe i just misunderstood them. i took this as an elective subject however my tutor is just so bad. he just gave us the slides and told us to read however there are no explanations as to what the codes are for and he gave us some exercises that weren't covered in his slides. anyway, i'll still try to get through this subject. above all, thanks everyone! cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You were kind of close. I'll break down the issues and give you the final code. First off, nothing wrong with your HTML. In terms of your function however there are some fundamental errors:

- `function add(3,5,5) {` - You don't want `3,5,5` here. This is where you list any arguments (variables that you want to use in your function). In the HTML you're already passing the values `3,5,5` to your function, so you want to create variables here that you'll use within your function. Example: `function add(a,b,c) {`
- You can get rid of `var a = +'3'; var b = +'5'; var c = +'5';`. You're already passing the values `3,5,5` into the function and have created the variables you need in the function's argument list. Explicitly declaring the variables a, b, and c again negates the point of passing values to a function.
- `var x = +a + +b + +c;` This is fine. Here you're coercing the values you passed into the function to numbers (instead of potentially strings) and adding them together (instead of concatenating). The `+` in front of each variable does the coersion.
- `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "x";` Again close. The issue with this line is the `"x"`. You want top remove the quotes around the variable `x`, otherwise you're telling JavaScript to use a literal `x` character instead of the `x` variable that holds your total.

Final result:

```js
function add(a, b, c) {
  var x = +a + +b + +c;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add(3,5,5)">
```

I **highly** recommend reading this intro to JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: holy moly! i've been reading about this for almost a day and this thing did it! thank you so much jo! i'll look into the links you've shared as well. cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, there is a lot wrong here but here is what I think you are trying to achieve. I strongly recommend you take some tutorials and check out some html/js fundamentals stuff.

```
<script>
  function add(a,b,c) {        
    var x = (a + b + c);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div id="result"></div> 
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add(3,5,5)">
</body>
```